# Does the resistance of a conductor depend on how the current flows through it?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electrical-resistance

For example if we take a cylinder with inner radius $a$ and outer radius $b$ would its resistance for the following three situations be the same?

(a) current flowing from inner face to outer face

(b) along the cylinder's height

(c) in a circular path within the cylinder that is along the circumference within the bulk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: **YES**

Essentially, resistance is a product of the material properties, width and length.

$$ R = \rho \frac{l}{A} $$

In the cases you described, the current experiences different widths and lengths, so the resistance is different too.

Comment: Thanks! Then just a follow up question how would you calculate the resistance in the third case i tried it but i was ending up with three differential elements in my equation and i was looking for a method that would avoid such sort of a double integration.

Comment: @AlexJokovich, If you have a new question, you should post it as a new question.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out resistance depends on the shape of the conductor and on the position of the wire connections. Also, the resistivity of the material of the conductor may be direction dependent. The law $J=\sigma E$ in such a case is generalized to $J_i = \sigma_{ij} E_j$, where $J$ is the current density, $E$ is the electric field and $\sigma_{ij}$ a tensor.